# Conditional Formatting three different conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have developed an Excel Spreadsheet that contains football (American term - soccer) positions, and I want to conditionally format the cells depending on their values.

This is the column that I have. 

CB

RW

RB

LB

RB

ST

LW

and so on and so forth. 
Now, CB, RB and LB are defensive positions, and I want to highlight them with a custom yellow fill.

I would have thought that the condition to be CB, RB, LB but it doesn't seem to work in the conditional formatting page.

How can I highlight them so they appear like this (bold being a yellow fill) but without the condition (text ends in B):

**CB**

RW

**RB**

**LB**

**RB**

ST

LW

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (if the positions go downwards from A2) would be to select the range starting from A2 and put the following formula:-

```
=RIGHT(A2)="B"
```

in Conditional Formatting | New Rule | Use a formula

but if you preferred you could also use

```
=OR(A2="CB",A2="RB",A2="LB")
```

Comment: On the second one, I did what you did by going to conditional formatting and inserting new rule and then used a formula BUT it says the message "You may not use unions, intersections or array constants for conditional
formatting criteria." - that is when I add the formula '=OR(A2={"CB","RB","LB"})' ... any solutions?

Comment: You are absolutely right, you'd have to use the more long-winded form of the formula =OR(A2="CB",A2="RB",A2="LB"). Sorry about that.